# E0144 значение типа “const char *” нельзя использовать для инициализации сущности типа “char *”

Tags: c++, строки, указатели, char

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <clocale>

using namespace std;


char *st_L[] = { "a = ", ", b = ", ", t_start = ", ", t_end = ", ", t_discr = ",

"Шаг ", "Значение - t ", "Значение - s(t) ",

"Результаты вычисления ", "исходных данных при ..\n",

"введённых данных при..\n\n" };


void out_(float*, float*, float*, float*, float*, char *s[], char *s1 = st_L[9]);
```

Comment: И? В чем ваш вопрос?

Comment: как исправить эту ошибку

Comment: Как "исправить эту ошибку" зависит от того, что нужно получить в результате. Например, использовать тип `const char *` там, где требуется тип `const char *`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, если только исправить :)

```
const char *st_L[] = { "a = ", ", b = ", ", t_start = ", ", t_end = ", ", t_discr = ",

...

void out_(float*, float*, float*, float*, float*, char *s[], const char *s1 = st_L[9]);
```

Comment: out_(&a, &b, &ts, &te, &td, st_L, st_L[10]); //

Comment: Ошибка (активно) E0304 отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция "out_", соответствующие списку аргументов

Comment: Естественно - вы не исправили свою функцию под исправленное объявление :) - только **кто** в этом виноват?